# assign an existing list to a blank list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I'm trying to check if a bunch of strings in a list called list9000 contain an "@" sign. What I want is to empty the list once it has 6 elements, but before clearing it to do a for loop checking the elements for any "@" signs. I've tried using del and other emptying techniques, but it just doesn't seem to work. Here's my work so far:

```
if( len(list9000) == 6):
        # print(list9000)
        i = list9000.count("@")
        if(i>1):
            amount9000 = amount9000 - i + 1
            numWrong = numWrong - i + 1
        list9000[:] = []
list9000.append(line)
```

This is just a snippet of my code. There are about 300 lines of other code. I am reading a text file, in which I add the lines of text in the file to my list. If I could solve this problem, I would be basically done with my project!

Edit: I've tried using del list9000[:], but it doesn't work.

**Update: ** I have printed out the length of the list, and it doesn't seem to be 6 most of the time, but rather increased by 6 every time.

Comment: You mean this is in a function and the list you passed in is not being cleared?

Comment: yes, i printed out the length and it just keeps on increasing

Comment: post an example of the input of this snippet, as well as the expected output.

Comment: As written, this code snippet cannot be tested for the behavior you describe. Please update the question with a minimum working example that will make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Can't you just do list9000.count("@") to see if it has an "@" sign?

Comment: **where** did you try `del list9000[:]`? If `list9000` is still referencing the original object you passed in, that is *exactly* how it should be done and should work. Please show us more of your code, with a *reproducible* example.

Comment: `i` can be written as `i = sum(['@' in x for x in list9000])` rather than using a loop and an if

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for the tip. it'd be great if the other problem can be resolved too

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have updated it. Also, I used del list9000[:] at the same place as list9000 = [] in my code above

Comment: @MikeDriscoll That will count the number of elements that are equal to "@" not the number of elements that contain "@".

Comment: @LynbrookVikings, Your example is still not reproducible...

Comment: @LynbrookVikings: then this is not your issue. You need to isolate a little further the problem. Assigning a blank list to a variable does just that. you need to start by asserting where the issue is, and how you make sure this is indeed the issue you are seing.

Comment: @merlin2011: sorry if i've been unclear. I am reading a text file, and the rest of the code is extremely lengthy, and I don't think they're entirely relevant. Do you want me to add the code where I read the text file? Sorry guys, but it hurts to see people vote down on my questions. I did the best I could, yet people still hate.

Comment: @Dunes - Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @LynbrookVikings, I doubt the people who are commenting under your question are the same people  who are downvoting you. I wouldn't take it personally. The goal for you should be to reproduce the problem in *as few lines of code as possible*. If your list only needs to be of length 6, you can just hardcode it in. There's no need to show us how you read the text file.

Comment: @merlin2011. The text file is thousand of lines long, so hardcoding it would be hard.

Comment: @LynbrookVikings, The point is that you need to do the work to cut it down to, let's say 10 lines that enable you to reproduce the problem. Presumably the problem does not happen *only* when you have thousands of lines of input. I presume this because the vast majority of problems we see at this level do not require massive inputs to reproduce.

Comment: @merlin2011: ok, I'll explain the problem to you. I am reading a text file that contains an email address and has a bunch of information under it. each new info is on a different line and each info is separated by at least one blank line. Each email contains five lines of information, making them 6 lines total. I want to get those 6 lines into a list. However, I count the amount of emails based on if the lines contain an "@" sign. However, sometimes the info will contain an "@" sign too, messing up my code. I think I've found the error. There is one instance when the info is not five lineslong

Answer (score 0):

You can just reassign list9000 to a new empty list object. But be careful, Python creates reference if you are assigning mutable objects. A simple `list9000[:] = []` should do the job to clear your list.

```
if( len(list9000) == 6):
    # print(list9000)
    i = 0
    for item in list9000:
        if("@" in item):
            i += i + 1
    if(i>1):
        amount9000 = amount9000 - i + 1
        numWrong = numWrong - i + 1
    list9000[:] = []
```

Comment: i still have the same problem :(

Comment: And you are sure that `if( len(list9000) == 6):` is evaluating to `True` at all? Did you step through your program using `pdb`? Or just insert a `print(len(list9000))` after the `list9000[:] = []`

Comment: Actually i may have found the problem. It's not entirely relevant